# Differences between "inform, tell, notify, and instruct"

Tags: word-usage

When and how to use these verbs correctly? I believe that even though they sound synonymous, every word has its own proper usage in a sentence.

According to Merriam Webster,

> **inform**- to impart or give information
>
> **tell**- to make known; to express in words
>
> **notify**- to give notice of or report the occurrence

Does it mean they are somewhat synonymous and can be used in a sentence interchangeably? For example,

1. I already ***informed/told/notified*** him about our plans this September.
2. Please **inform/notify** our classmates that we will have a long quiz on our History subject.
3. The police ***notified/told/informed*** the family that this is not just a mere case of suicide.

Answer (score 2):

They can often be used interchangeably, but *tell* has a more general and wider meaning and application than *inform* and *notify* which means that the latter two can often be replaced by *tell* but not always vice versa.

Here's an example:

> - He **told** him that changes would be made.
> - He **notified** him that changes would be made.
> - He **informed** him that changes would be made.

They can be used interchangeably in the above sentences, but have a look at this:

> - He **told** his grandson the Christmas story.
> - *He **notified** his grandson the Christmas story.
> - *He **informed** his grandson the Christmas story.

You could say that he *informed/notified his grandson **of/about** the Christmas story*, but that would completely change the meaning.

And then there are cases where it is doubtful:

> - He **told** his grandson how he met his wife.
> - He **notified** his grandson how he met his wife.
> - He **informed** his grandson how he met his wife.

I'm sure you'll notice that in this case *notify* and *inform* do not really work. They're not appropriate in this more informal context. Here *to tell* denotes a more story-telling way of conveying information. I doubt the man would tell his grandson in a formal and subjective way how he met his wife, which is what *notify* and *inform* mean.

Answer (score 0):

What is being communicated should help to decide which is better, though no doubt there can be crossover. In your examples:

> 1) I already **told** him about our plans this September.

because "our plans" would be considered general information.

> 2) Please **inform** our classmates that we will have a long quiz on our History subject.

since "we will have a long quiz" is information that they should pay attention to.

> 3) The police **notified** the family that this is not just a mere case of suicide.

Official information would generally be considered a notice.

More context would make it easier to decide which is better.